# Unable to generate signing report with Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running Android Studio on a Linux laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 re-installed. Before the re-installation of the OS, my apps ran fine under Studio, but now each time I start any of them, Gmail authentication fails with a return code of 0.

I suspect a problem with an SHA-1 certificate, but I can't examine it because I can't generate a signing report (starting down the rabbit hole):

> ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/OpenComments3$ gradle signingReport

Command 'gradle' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install gradle  # version 7.2, or
sudo apt  install gradle  # version 4.4.1-13
See 'snap info gradle' for additional versions.
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/OpenComments3$ sudo snap install gradle
[sudo] password for ruomini:
error: This revision of snap "gradle" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform
arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to,
which may put your system at risk.

```
   If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --classic.
```

ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/OpenComments3$ sudo snap install gradle --classic
gradle 7.2 from Snapcrafters✪ installed
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/OpenComments3$ gradle signingReport

Welcome to Gradle 7.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Toolchain support for Scala
- More cache hits when Java source files have platform-specific line endings
- More resilient remote HTTP build cache behavior

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration cache is an incubating feature.
Calculating task graph as no configuration cache is available for tasks: signingReport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'OpenComments3'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.9.9/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.9.9.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.9.9/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.9.9.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.9.9/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.9.9.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.9.9/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.9.9.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/OpenComments3$ ~/gradlew signingReport

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /home/uomini/jdk-17.0.7

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/OpenComments3$ gradle signingReport
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration cache is an incubating feature.
Calculating task graph as no configuration cache is available for tasks: signingReport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'OpenComments3'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/com/google/gms/google-services/4.4.0/google-services-4.4.0.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.9.9/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.9.9.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.9.9/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.9.9.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.9.9/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.9.9.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-crashlytics-gradle/2.9.9/firebase-crashlytics-gradle-2.9.9.pom'.
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/OpenComments3$

*******************************End of rabit hole****************************
Obviously, my system has been totally hosed (thank you, Déjà Dup!). Anyone have advice on how to get the signing report or otherwise fix this problem?